# Is there a way to allow users to bulk upload documents into SharePoint and prefill in metadata from another system?

Tags: document, tagging

Is there a way to allow users to bulk upload documents into SharePoint and prefill in metadata from another system?

I would like to use the drag and drop functionality of SharePoint 2013 but need to add the same metadata for all documents.  Is it possible to pass these parameters into SharePoint?  How would one do this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy solution to this that doesn't involve any workflows or event receivers...

You can create a folder or series of folders and use location specific default values for your metadata column to assign the managed metadata terms depending on which folder they are dropped in.

Once you drop the item in the folder and the metadata gets assigned, you can then move the files out of the folders and the metadata terms will remain. Alternatively, you could just view the library with no folders, but the folder will still appear in the url path for the document, so I recommend just moving them out of the folder.

---

You can set-up "Location-Based Metadata Defaults" by going (from the ribbon) to Library -> Library Settings, then under General Settings select 'Column default value settings.' On the left-hand side you'll see a list of your folders under the heading 'Location to configure.' I will typically create just one folder and change the default value depending on what items I'm uploading, but you could create multiple folders for whatever terms you want to assign.

Once you have this setup, you can bulk upload files into the specified folders and they will automatically be given the corresponding metadata values for that folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 3-rd party solutions. For example, from VirtoSoftware: [Html5 Bulk File Upload](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/bulk/virto-html5-bulk-file-upload) or [Silverlight based Bulk File Upload](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/bulk/virto-bulk-file-upload).

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing the same metadata for all the documents, you could create a workflow to run on creation and assign whatever metadata you want to all of the items.