# Automating Upload of large volume files to Document library in SharePoint 2013 Office365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, managed-metadata, metadata

I have searched in the internet for multiple tools and none of tools are supporting to pre-fill metadata values for a document. I just wanted to know is there any tool which can automate the process of uploading large volume files into Document library with metadata values pre-filled.

I'm looking this process for SharePoint 2013 Office 365 environment.

Comment: Are you looking for a non-code solution only?

Comment: Yes Adam... I'm looking for some readymade tools which can do this process... like "ShareGate" or "cloudiway" but the problem is with these tools we cannot prefill the metadata values.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-populate your metadata values using event receivers (Item Added) on the list.   This would require custom code, however.

**EDIT**

There is a program out on CodePlex that might work for you:

https://github.com/MadAboutImport/DIFS

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a project downloading 20.000 doc's from Hummingbird(!), convert them to docx  and uploading then to sharepoint. The metadata were in a csv file - we used tzunami for the export
I tried to find a tool like yours but with no avail, so I went to c#. I could upload the project (V.S. 2013) if you want.

If you don't have weird fields (like lookup, choises, people picker) I suggest you go with access. First, you make your metadata a xls file, along with the filename and sort them by filename. Then you connect your document library to an access table (sort by name) and copy from xls-paste to access.
You can also do it in datasheet, and you can fill up choises!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the below tool, they did us demo long time ago and show some metadata tagging. May be help you.

[Bulk Upload:](http://www.metavistech.com/category/sharepoint-users) Import files from a file share while enriching the content with metadata from file system attributes, folder names or existing SharePoint controls such as managed metadata fields

If you check, they allow you upload the files and at the end give you control so that you can select many items and update the properties at once.

http://sharepointsnapple.com/enhanced-document-upload/

Same thing from here:

http://harmon.ie/documentation/sharepoint/outlook/uploading

Otherwise you can write your own piece of code.

Comment: Bulk upload is a bad link now.   I know it is old but this question has little current updates and I was going to post something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Go built-in if you can and use location specific metadata folders (maybe just as easy and certainly cheaper!) posted from another one of [my answers here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111054/is-there-a-way-to-allow-users-to-bulk-upload-documents-into-sharepoint-and-prefi/111096#111096):

> You can create a folder or series of folders and use location specific
>   default values for your metadata column to assign the managed metadata
>   terms depending on which folder they are dropped in.
>
> Once you drop the item in the folder and the metadata gets assigned,
>   you can then move the files out of the folders and the metadata terms
>   will remain. Alternatively, you could just view the library with no
>   folders, but the folder will still appear in the url path for the
>   document, so I recommend just moving them out of the folder.
>
> You can set-up "Location-Based Metadata Defaults" by going (from the
>   ribbon) to Library -> Library Settings, then under General Settings
>   select 'Column default value settings.' On the left-hand side you'll
>   see a list of your folders under the heading 'Location to configure.'
>   I will typically create just one folder and change the default value
>   depending on what items I'm uploading, but you could create multiple
>   folders for whatever terms you want to assign.
>
> Once you have this setup, you can bulk upload files into the specified
>   folders and they will automatically be given the corresponding
>   metadata values for that folder.
>
> You can then easily move all of the items out of the folders you used
>   to give them default metadata values (so that you have a flat library
>   structure). Also worth noting, my other answer addresses text/choice
>   fields specifically, but this technique works for all kinds of fields,
>   including managed metadata.

Useful to note this works for all data types (including managed metadata)

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool DMS-Shuttle for SP. It supports bulk upload and bulk edit metadata. But you have to do this in two steps: first upload a folder structure with documents to a document library and then run batch edit metadata for all documents within this library or a subfolder.

The tool is not free, but there is a trial version for 15 days:
http://www.dms-shuttle.com/downloads

Answer (score -1):

http://www.sharepointbasic.com/2016/12/upload-multiplebulk-files-to-sharepoint.html

Refer the above link . it uses powershell to upload multiple files